# Code keeps eating Memory

Tags: c#, linq, memory

So basically this code asked how many items do I want to generate but after that just keep running without response.
And just eats up ram.

What I want it to do is ask amount of items to generate then state its name and its stats.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestingRNG
{
class Program
{
    public static Random Random = new Random();
    public static int dropRate, itemAmmount;
    public static List<Items> Loot = new List<Items>();
    public static List<string> WeaponList = new List<string> { "Staff", "Sword", "Dagger", "Wand", "Axe", "Mace" };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Programs();
    }
    public static void Programs()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many items do you want to generate");
        itemAmmount = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; 0 < itemAmmount; i++)
        {
            dropRate = Random.Next(1, 6);
            Loot.Add(new Items(dropRate));
        }
        foreach (var Item in Loot)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Item.Name);
            if (WeaponList.Contains(Item.ItemType))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Item.Damage);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Item.HP);
                Console.WriteLine(Item.MANA);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `for (int i = 0; 0 < itemAmmount; i++)` --> `for (int i = 0; i < itemAmmount; i++)`

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int i = 0; 0 < itemAmmount; i++)
```

You're not checking the loop counter, you're comparing 0 with `itemAmount`. That's an infinite loop.

Try `for (int i = 0; i < itemAmmount; i++)` instead.

You can use code snippets in Visual Studio to avoid such errors. Type 'for' and press Tab twice, and a code snippet for `for` loop will be inserted with possibility to rename `i` and `length`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; 0 < itemAmmount; i++)
{
    dropRate = Random.Next(1, 6);
    Loot.Add(new Items(dropRate));
}
```

you set `itemAmmount`, and never alter it.  The only way your loop will exit is if `itemAmmount` decreased (to below 0).

Fix your `for` loop, so that it makes logical sense:

```
for(int i=0; i<itemAmmount; i++)
```